# Wordpress Line Break <br/>

Tags: wordpress

In wordpress I'm unable to do a line break without going into the text editor and doing

```
    <br/>
```

Even then it tends to reset itself. Multiple "enters" don't work either.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean you want to line break on front end side ?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the sections inside <p> tags </p>. Wordpress will always remove <br/> tags in the visual editor.

Comment: Yeah I have and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some themes are made so they escape extra line breaks, and that could be the reason you can't make any.

Without knowing your theme, I can't help you much, but you could create a custom shortcode just for breaklines or even style it like a divider or something:

```
// divider shortcode
function divider_func(){
    return '<div class="divider"></div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'divider', 'divider_func' );
```

then just use CSS to make it however you want. something like

```
.divider{margin-top:20px}
```

Now just put "[divider]" (without the quotemarks) in your post text where you want the gap to appear

Comment: This is not useful answer if you don't know about any theme then how can you give suggestion. First comment it out in question then give answer.

Comment: What are you talking about?! I pointed out why inserting <br> doesn't work in SOME themes, and I gave an alternative way of achieving the same thing - and using shortcodes works 100% :)

Also - if you have plain users entering content (e.g. not a web developer), it's much better for them to use shortcodes in the normal editor than making them switch to HTML editor and input HTML tags manually

Comment: Thanks Skipp, I tried your suggestion but wordpress just printed out [divider], any ideas why?

Comment: I know it's a silly question but, did you include the function I wrote in your theme's functions.php file? I tested it on the latest WP version and it works.

Comment: Sorry silly mistake I use a } at the end of the last one, it works thanks!